# Плавная анимация плюс и минуса при клике

Tags: jquery, css, анимация, css-animation

```js
$(".summary").click(function(){
 if ($("#hotel-facilities").is(":hidden")){
  $("#hotel-facilities").slideDown("slow");
  $(".summary:before").css({"-webkit-transform":"translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(0)"});
} else {
 $("#hotel-facilities").hide("slow");
 $(".summary:before").css({"-webkit-transform":"translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-90)"});
}

});
```

```css
.is-hidden {
 display: none;
}
.summary {
 font-size: 14px;
 padding: 14px 40px;
 position: relative;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 font-weight: 400;
}
.summary:before {
 /*-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(0);*/
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-90deg);
    will-change: translate,rotate;
}
.summary:after {
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    will-change: translate,opacity;

}
.summary:after,
.summary:before {
 content: "";
 width: 14px;
 height: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 background-color: #37454d;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 opacity: 1;
 left: 21px;
 contain: strict;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="details">
 <h4 class="summary" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="hotel-facilities" aria-controls="hotel-facilities" tabindex="0">Hotel facilities</h4>
  <div id="hotel-facilities" class="is-hidden">
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">24-hour reception (4923)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Всем привет.Есть задачка чтобы при клике плюс плавно стал минусом все готово почти просто нужно с помощью `jquery` при клике добавить нужный стиль к нужному элементу вот тут я застрял.Ключевой момент при клике нужно в классе `.summary:before` сменить анимацию `transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-90deg);` на  `-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(0);`и все.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном примере мы не обращаемся к псевдоэлементу :before через jquery а добавляем класс, который изменяет его положение.

```js
$(".summary").click(function() {

    if ($("#hotel-facilities").is(":hidden")) {
    
      $("#hotel-facilities").slideDown("slow");
      $(".summary").addClass("open");
        
    }else {

        $("#hotel-facilities").hide("slow");
        $(".summary").removeClass("open");
    
    }

});
```

```css
.is-hidden {
 display: none;
}
.summary {
 font-size: 14px;
 padding: 14px 40px;
 position: relative;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 font-weight: 400;
}
.summary:before {
 /*-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(0);*/
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-90deg);
    will-change: translate,rotate;
}
.summary:after {
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    will-change: translate,opacity;

}
.summary.open:before{ /* добавочный класс */
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-0deg);
    width:0;
}
.summary:after,
.summary:before {
 content: "";
 width: 14px;
 height: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 background-color: #37454d;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 opacity: 1;
 left: 21px;
 contain: strict;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="details">
 <h4 class="summary" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="hotel-facilities" aria-controls="hotel-facilities" tabindex="0">Hotel facilities</h4>
  <div id="hotel-facilities" class="is-hidden">
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">24-hour reception (4923)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное .А что я намудрил я не понял :( ? @Kirill Korushkin

Comment: Мне просто показалось, что код избыточен для такой задачи. Но это не в обиду, просто я привык делать такие фишки через готовые элементы страницы, без псевдоэлементов. Но, кстати, пока разбирал пример, почерпнул для себя новый подход, спасибо ;)

Comment: вам спасибо @Kirill Korushkin